# Merging some columns of two mysql tables where id = fileid

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables

```
TableA
filedata_id | user_id | filename
1           | 1       | file.txt
2           | 1       | file2.txt


TableB   
a_id        | date    | filedataid | counter | state | cat_id | subcat_id | med_id
99          | 1242144 | 1          | 2       | v     | 55     |  56       | 90
100         | 1231232 | 2          | 3       | i     | 44     |  55       | 110
```

I want to move columns cat_id, subcat_id, med_id to TableA where tableA.filedata_id = TableB.filedataid

edit: The result should be a schema change in tableA so it looks like the following and also have the data from those columns in tableB:

```
TableA
filedata_id | user_id | filename  | cat_id | subcat_id | med_id
1           | 1       | file.txt  | 55     | 56        | 90
2           | 1       | file2.txt | 44     | 55        | 110
```

and so on.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Do you wish to change the schema of TableA or simply create a query to display the data accordingly?

Comment: I should have mentioned before. I want to change the schema of tableA and import the data from those specific columns in tableB

Comment: @garg see my answer below, you need to alter  `tablea` and add columns on it, then update the records by joining tablea and tableB.

Comment: @garg Did'n any answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You can use `INNER JOIN` for that:</strike>

```
SELECT t1.filedata_id, t1.user_id, t1.filename
      ,t2.cat_id, t2.subcat_id, t2.med_id
FROM TableA t1 
INNER JOIN TableB t2 
ON t1.filedata_id = t2.filedataid
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ba4b/1)

**UPDATE:**

You can change the schema of `TableA` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
Add column cat_id int, 
Add column  subcat_id int, 
Add column  med_id int;
```

And update new columns of `TableA` from `TableB` like this:

```
UPDATE tableA t1 
       JOIN tableB t2 
       ON t1.filedata_id = t2.filedataid
SET t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id,
    t1.subcat_id = t2.subcat_id,
    t1.med_ID = t2.med_ID;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a53c5/2)

For more see [MySQL: ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) and [MySQL: UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: I'm sorry. I had incomplete information. I needed the schema of tableA to change, and then the data from the columns was to be imported where filedata_id and filedataid were equal

Comment: @garg So do you want to alter tableA and input some fields of tableB and it's data?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can use `INNER JOIN` on this,</strike>

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.cat_id,
        b.subcat_id,
        b.med_ID
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            On a.filedata_id = b.filedataid
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7026e/3)

seeing in your comment, you need to alter the table and add columns on it, to do that you need to execute this DDL statement,

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD COLUMN cat_id int;
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD COLUMN subcat_id int;
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD COLUMN med_ID int;
```

then you can now update the rows of your `TableA` based on the values of `TableB`

```
UPDATE tableA t1 INNER JOIN tableB t2 
        ON a.filedata_id = b.filedataid
SET a.cat_id = b.cat_id,
    a.subcat_id = b.subcat_id,
    a.med_ID = b.med_ID
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to look at the [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) at the multiple table section.

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables.
>   However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table
>   UPDATE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the
>   join. Its syntax is described in Section 13.2.8.2, “JOIN Syntax”. Here
>   is an example:  UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE
>   items.id=month.id;

Something like

```
UPDATE  TableA, TableB
SET     TableA.cat_id = TableB.cat_id,
        TableA.subcat_id = TableB.subcat_id,
        TableA.med_ID = TableB.med_ID
WHERe   TableA.filedata_id = TableB.filedataid
```

For altering a table (Adding columns to TableA), take a look at [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)